# Neo4j add property from CSV to a node

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a label Person which contains millions of nodes. The nodes have some properties and I am trying to add a new property to the nodes from a CSV file.
I am trying to match them by the person's forename and surname but the query is too slow. The query is:

`USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///personaldata.csv' AS line1
MATCH (p:Person {forename:line1.forename, surname:line1.surname})
SET p.newPersonNumber=line1.newPersonNumber`

I left the query running for maybe an hour before I terminated it.
Am I doing something wrong?
Note that I have indexes on `forename` and `surname` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try profiling the query to see if it really uses the indices:

```
PROFILE
WITH "qwe" AS forename, "asd" AS surname
MATCH (p:Person {forename: forename, surname: surname})
RETURN p
```

If it doesn't, you can force it:

```
WITH "qwe" AS forename, "asd" AS surname
MATCH (p:Person {forename: forename, surname: surname})
USING INDEX p:Person(forename)
USING INDEX p:Person(surname)
RETURN p
```

As mentioned in the [Cypher refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/3.0/) (emphasis mine):

> Index usage can be enforced, when Cypher uses a suboptimal index **or more than one index should be used**.

See also the chapter on [`USING`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-using).

---

**Update**

Since using multiple indices on the same node is not currently supported, let's focus back on why the query is slow, and whether it actually does something. You can profile the actual `LOAD CSV` for a subset, and see if the data matches anything:

```
PROFILE
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///personaldata.csv' AS line1
WITH line1
LIMIT 10
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person {forename:line1.forename, surname:line1.surname})
RETURN p, line1.newPersonNumber
```

That way, you can check that the `MATCH` finds something (i.e. the forename and surname don't need trimming or something), and you can also check which index is more beneficial to the query: since only 1 index will be used, then the results will be filtered on the other property, and it'll be faster if you use the most discriminant index. If all the persons are Johns, you'd better use the index on surname, but if they're all Does, use the index on forename. If they're all John Does, you have a duplication problem... Anyway, comparing the numbers on the filtering steps between the 2 profiles (with either index) should give you an idea of the distribution of the indices.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
The query is using only one index, not both of them.
After running

 `USING INDEX p:Person(forename)
  USING INDEX p:Person(surname)`
I get `Multiple hints for same variable are not supported (line 3, column 13 (offset: 109))
"USING INDEX p:Person(forename)"`.
I think the indices are not the issue because I let the query running for some time and then check if there are nodes with that property like this:

`MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE EXISTS (p.newPersonNumber)
RETURN p`, but I got 0 rows returned.

Comment: I've updated the answer to focus on the debugging and profiling of the query.

Comment: Using `PROFILE` I see that `MATCH` finds results so I guess the query is written correctly. Also more beneficial for me is having index on `forename` (like it is right now). I don't know what else might be the problem. Also note that the CSV file is 4.7 GB.

Comment: Regardless of the size of the CSV (which impacts total run time), since you have `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`, you should see some results after a while. Run the updating query on a subset, measure how long it takes (to estimate how long the complete run will last) and check that the property was added to a few nodes. No typo in the name of the CSV column either (`line1.newPersonNumber`)?